# Java Swing filling multiple JTextFields with data from a text file

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, java.util.scanner, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a Contacts Book using swing and I have a problem with filling my text fields with data from a file.

I have boxes for first name, surname, address and phone number (string) and the structure of text file is like this:

```
Name
Surname
Address
Phone
Name
Surname
Address
Phone
...
```

I have an ArrayList to hold the contacts, and when instead of reading data from the file I use contacts.add(String, String, String, String) I successfully display the data in TextFields.

I tried this to read from the file, but it doesn't seem to work.

try {

```
    this.myFile = new File("contacts.txt");
    this.scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        contact = new Contact(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
        contacts.add(contact);

    }
}   
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Not found");
}
finally {
    if (scan != null) {
        scan.close();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("empty");
    }
}
```

Would it be easier/better to use a database instead?
Thanks

Comment: Is contacts an ArrayList of contact objects? Plus what kind of an error did you get?

Comment: yes
ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @EmreDalkiran I get a NoSuchElementException

Comment: I edited my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking for one next line but trying to read next three lines after first one without checking.

```
scan.next();// reads until next token
```

**Try this**

```
scanner.nextLine();//read until the end of line.
```

You should put your logic in a way that it checks before each scan and creates a new contact object between 4 scans to store information.

Comment: like this?
contact = new Contact(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next() + scan.nextLine());

Comment: No, change each of scan.next() to scan.nextLine (); in addition to that, you need to check before each scan if it is null or not. Plus, I believe that your contact class has 4 variables, not 5. That is the reason you get that error. Your contact constructor expects 4 arguments. You are trying to call it with 5 arguments.